# Change icons border when click the bottom tab bar in Swift

Tags: swift

I have custom bottom navigation bar in IOS application, everythings work very well,  and I want to change bottom navigation items tint color when I click the items, and I was use the

```
self.imgView.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
self.imgView.tintColor = .red
```

in `isSelected`, and it is change whole icons border tint color. I do not know where I miss, any idea?

**screenshot:**

[image]

**RootStackTabViewController:**

```
class RootStackTabViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var bottomStack: UIStackView!
    
    var currentIndex = 0
    
    lazy var tabs: [StackItemView] = {
        var items = [StackItemView]()
        for _ in 0..<5 {
            items.append(StackItemView.newInstance)
        }
        return items
    }()
    
    lazy var tabModels: [BottomStackItem] = {
        return [
            BottomStackItem(title: "Home", image: "home"),
            BottomStackItem(title: "Favorites", image: "heart"),
            BottomStackItem(title: "Search", image: "search"),
            BottomStackItem(title: "Profile", image: "user"),
            BottomStackItem(title: "Settings", image: "settings")
        ]
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupTabs()
    }

    func setupTabs() {
        for (index, model) in self.tabModels.enumerated() {
            let tabView = self.tabs[index]
            model.isSelected = index == 0
            tabView.item = model
            tabView.delegate = self
            self.bottomStack.addArrangedSubview(tabView)
        }
    }

}
```

**StackItemView:**

```
protocol StackItemViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func handleTap(_ view: StackItemView)
}

class StackItemView: UIView {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var highlightView: UIView!
    
    private let higlightBGColor = UIColor(hexString: "1160FB")
    
    static var newInstance: StackItemView {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(
            StackItemView.className(),
            owner: nil,
            options: nil
        )?.first as! StackItemView
    }
    
    weak var delegate: StackItemViewDelegate?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.addTapGesture()
    }
  
    var isSelected: Bool = false {
        willSet {
            self.updateUI(isSelected: newValue)
            self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
            self.imgView.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            self.imgView.tintColor = .red
    
            
        }
    }
    
    var item: Any? {
        didSet {
            self.configure(self.item)
        }
    }
    
    private func configure(_ item: Any?) {
        guard let model = item as? BottomStackItem else { return }
        self.titleLabel.text = model.title
        self.imgView.image = UIImage(named: model.image)
        self.isSelected = model.isSelected
    }
    
    private func updateUI(isSelected: Bool) {
        guard let model = item as? BottomStackItem else { return }
        model.isSelected = isSelected
        let options: UIView.AnimationOptions = isSelected ? [.curveEaseIn] : [.curveEaseOut]
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0,
                       initialSpringVelocity: 0.5,
                       options: options,
                       animations: {
            self.titleLabel.text = isSelected ? model.title : ""
            let color = isSelected ? self.higlightBGColor : .white
            self.highlightView.backgroundColor = color
            (self.superview as? UIStackView)?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    
}

extension StackItemView {
    
    func addTapGesture() {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                action: #selector(handleGesture(_:)))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    
    @objc
    func handleGesture(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.delegate?.handleTap(self)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
self.imgView.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

is incomplete. The method returns an image (cf. [Apple’s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624153-withrenderingmode)) and it should thus be

```
self.imgView.image = self.imgView.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

Comment: tnx so much for ur answer, but it change all icons tint color, I want to change icons tint color when I click the icons, when I click it must be red, others must be black for example

Comment: Then you just have to check the new value of isSelected in willSet. If it is true, you can change he tint color to red. If it is false, you have to explicitly set it back to white. Your code currently sets .red in all cases.

Comment: I do not want to change all items tint color at the same time, I want to  change, when item selected.  :) how we can solve it ?